# Apache Tomcat is showing an already made WAR file instead of the home page at localhost:8080

Tags: java, tomcat

Hello I am trying to pass my project to my instructor through war file. I have already made the war file and I am trying to check if the war file works. But when I run the tomcat and input the `localhost:8080` in the browser a WAR file is being deployed instead of the home page

Startup command prompt:
[image]

localhost:8080
[image]

What I am expecting:
[image]
ApacheTomcat Webapps Folder:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you work with a tomcat version customized by your instructor.

By default when you take a tomcat downloaded from the internet "as-is" you should create a WAR (say, `calculator.war`) and put into `webapps` folder and after that you'll be able to access it by `localhost:8080/calculator`. That's the default behavior, but its still possible to deploy your custom war to be accessible through `localhost:8080` as you've described.

There are a couple of ways to do so, but it looks like in your case there is an entry in `$CATALINA_HOME$\conf\server.xml` that looks something like this:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true"
  autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="Calculator"></Context>
     ....
</Host>
```

Or alternatively you have `$CATALINA_HOME\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml` file
that contains information about the `Calculator` war.

Another direction to check is that in your IDE you don't create `ROOT.war` out of your `Calculator` project. This is also a way to deploy stuff in the root context path.

All-in-all I suggest you reading [This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application) because the chances are that you somehow use one of these methods of deployment.